# AttributeError when calling method

Tags: python

I have a class Conf:

```
class Conf(object):
  def __init__(self):
    pass
  def __setattr__(self,name,value):
    current_container().__set_conf(name,value)
```

The current_container() returns an instance of the interface class:

```
class interface(Container):
  def __init__(self,name):
    pass
  def __set_conf(self,name,value):
    ...
    super(interface,self).__set_conf(name,value)
```

after calling `conf.ip=...` the exception is arised:

```
AttributeError: 'interface' object has no attribute '_Conf__set_conf'
```

It seems that python adding prefix "_Conf" to a method name. How to avoid this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're being victim of [*name mangling*](http://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/expressions.html?highlight=name%20mangling#atom-identifiers), designed mainly to avoid accidents. If you want to specify that `_set_conf` method should be private, with only one underscore is sufficiently communicative.

[Private Variables and Class-local References](http://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/classes.html?highlight=name%20mangling#private-variables-and-class-local-references) provides more information about the utility of this feature.